# apache2 proxy balancer pass to single member

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

I'm having issues getting the urls /api and /admin to pass to the single app server, 10.10.0.56.. It is still getting loadbalanced (and failing half the time), like all the other requests. Not sure what is going on.

```
<Proxy balancer://stagecluster>
       BalancerMember http://10.10.0.56 loadfactor=5
       BalancerMember http://10.10.0.57 loadfactor=5
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerName stage.mydomain.com

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.10.0.111
</Location>

ProxyPass /server-status !

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

ProxyPass /admin http://10.10.0.56/admin
ProxyPassReverse /admin http://10.10.0.56/admin

ProxyPass /api http://10.10.0.56/api
ProxyPassReverse /api http://10.10.0.56/api

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Updated the config and moved the proxypass rules above any rewrites and balancer definitions and fixed it.

Comment: Is it possible you oversimplified this example? I don't seem to see you proxying anything through stagecluster with this config.